# Stacked bar plot : y axis gets

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a set of test data like this

```
 week       reason         gross   
    2   Наличные            356.54
    6   FuelUp             1157.54
    7   Альянс              706.54
   10   FlashPay           1567.54
   10   Наличные            135.54
   19   FuelUp             3045.54
   19   Карты Сбербанка     723.54
   19   Наличные           1230.54
   24   FuelUp              875.54
   27   FlashPay           1260.54
   28   Альянс              556.54
   33   FlashPay           9756.54
   33   Ваучеры             756.54
   37   Ваучеры             473.54
   38   Ваучеры             358.54
   41   Карты Сбербанка     600.54
   49   Наличные            100.00
```

And I made a stacked bar plot with this code:

```
query$week = factor(query$week,ordered=TRUE)                       
p <- ggplot(query,aes(x=week,y=gross,fill=reason)) + theme_light() +
        geom_col(position="stack") +
        scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T) +
        labs(x="Неделя 2020")
print(p)
```

where query is just that pice of data (that came from PostgrSQL. So far, so good but such a code results in such a picture with an incomlete Y axis.
[image]
Why is that and what should I do to "prolong" tics and labels on the axis?

Comment: What is the data type of the 'gross' variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `gross` variable is not a number.

Starting data, where `gross` is a string (or factor), not a number:

```r
query <- structure(list(week = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), .Label = c("2", 
"6", "7", "10", "19", "24", "27", "28", "33", "37", "38", "41", 
"49"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), reason = c("", "FuelUp", 
"", "FlashPay", "", "FuelUp", "_", "", "FuelUp", "FlashPay", 
"", "FlashPay", "", "", "", "_", ""), gross = c("356.54", "1157.54", 
"706.54", "1567.54", "135.54", "3045.54", "723.54", "1230.54", 
"875.54", "1260.54", "556.54", "9756.54", "756.54", "473.54", 
"358.54", "600.54", "100.00")), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
```

(My hasty import butchered the `reason` ... that'll skew the display/legend a bit but does not change the premise of my answer.)

The plot:

```r
p <- ggplot(query,aes(x=week,y=gross,fill=reason)) + theme_light() +
        geom_col(position="stack") +
        scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T) +
        labs(x="Неделя 2020")
```

[image: ggplot2 with incorrect y-axis]

If we convert it to `numeric`, the plot looks more normal.

```r
query$gross <- as.numeric(query$gross)
p <- ggplot(query,aes(x=week,y=gross,fill=reason)) + theme_light() +
        geom_col(position="stack") +
        scale_fill_viridis(discrete = T) +
        labs(x="Неделя 2020")
p
```

[image: ggplot2, fixed y-axis]

Comment: Argh... I see. Does it always treat those as strings, so I have to explicitly convert them into numbers?

Comment: The fact that they are strings *here* could be due to anything, including: how you read them in (e.g., `read.table`, `read_csv`, `read_excel`) and/or something you did before the plot attempt. I really don't have a way of knowing *why* with what we know here.

Comment: However, since your plot shows the y values in numeric order and my plot shows them in alphabetic order, that suggests that yours are `factor`s, not `character`. For that, you'll need `as.numeric(as.character(query$gross))`. If you're on R < 4.0.0, then the default for `read.table` and `data.frame` and friends is `stringsAsFactors=TRUE`, so that might be a clue where to look. If that's the case, if I were you I would go back to the data-import step and fix it *first* and then re-run all intermediate code ... because sometimes "math" on factors can appear to work without error.

Comment: Accepted. Did not know before I should do this. Sorry.